# Javascript BTOA vs base64 in bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script, javascript, base64

I need to convert a username and password combination into base64 before sending to an API.

The javascript BTOA function is working for me, but when I try to use base64 command in bash I get slightly different results.

**Javascript:**

```
btoa("hello");                   # aGVsbG8=
btoa("username:password");       # dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQ=
btoa("testing");                 # dGVzdGluZw==
```

**Bash:**

```
echo hello | base64              # aGVsbG8K
echo username:password | base64  # dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzc3dvcmQK
echo testing | base64            # dGVzdGluZwo=
```

Results are always similar but different.

Server expects the JS style encoding, but I need to use bash.

Why are the results different but similar? How can I produce the results from javascript with bash?

Comment: linking: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/117549

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`echo` "helpfully" adds a newline to the output (based on the specs in the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html)), so base64 dutifully encodes that as well.

Tell `echo` to not add a newline:

```
$ echo hello | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o  \n
0000006
$ echo -n hello | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
```

Or better, use `printf`:

```
$ printf '%s' hello | od -c
0000000   h   e   l   l   o
0000005
$ printf '%s' hello | base64
aGVsbG8=
$ echo -n hello | base64
aGVsbG8=
```