# Why does converting from base64 and back garble the end of this string?

Tags: base64

Command:

```
echo "HelloWorld==" | base64 -d | base64
```

Output:

```
HelloWorlQ==
```

Why is my `d` now a `Q`?

**Edit:**

I am not trying to start with arbitrary data and base64 encode it.  My intention is to start with Base64 and end with Base64, having only produced a binary value in the interim.

**Edit 2**:

I have noticed that it does not happen if the input string has is a multiple of four characters, so I think it is an interaction with the padding somehow:

```
❯ echo 'abcdefghij==' | base64 -d | base64
abcdefghig==

❯ echo 'abcdefgh' | base64 -d | base64 
abcdefgh
```

**Edit 3**

Removed confusing mention of the `-i` flag, which turned out to have nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: Related? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383711/117549

Comment: Thanks @JeffSchaller but I don't think so.  Newline is not a valid base64 character, so it should be ignored.  Also using `echo -n` doesn't change anything.

Comment: please change your example so that it provides valid base64 input to `base64 -id`.  e.g. `echo SGVsbG8gV29ybGQhPT0K | base64 -id | base64`.   or, at least, the actual data you're piping.  Piping `Hello World!==` into it just makes the question confusing.   BTW, this also answers the question - whatever your actual input is, it is not valid base64.

Comment: @cas I have removed references to, and usage of the `-i` flag, because I agree it was confusing.  I'm leaving the invalid base64 because if it were suddenly valid then the question wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's an interaction with the padding.

Let's look at your actual encoded data by decoding it, and (since it's not an ASCII string) convert it into binary:

```
$ base64 -d <<<'HelloWorld==' | xxd -b
00000000: 00011101 11101001 01100101 10100001 01101010 00101011  ..e.j+
00000006: 10010101                                               .
```

This is the data that `HelloWorld==` is the base64 encoding of. [Philip Couling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/537383/116858) explains the intricacies of the decoding of the final `ld==` part and that, in a way, only a third of the data encoded by the `d` is actually used when decoding the data.  Below I'm showing where the `Q` comes from when you re-encode the data.

Let's repeat that binary:

```
00011101 11101001 01100101 10100001 01101010 00101011 10010101
```

In groups of six bits (which is what the base64 encoder will use):

```
000111 011110 100101 100101 101000 010110 101000 101011 100101 01
```

This padded with four zero bits at the end to make 10 complete 6-bit codes:

```
000111 011110 100101 100101 101000 010110 101000 101011 100101 010000
```

The `010000` is the `Q` you see when you re-encode the data (see [the base64 table of codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table)).

Answer (score 5):

`HelloWorld==` contains information which cannot be decoded, and isn't technically valid Base64 since they should in general be `0` padded.  The extra `1`s this contains will be ignored and lost when you `echo "HelloWorld==" | base64 -d`.

To explain...

Base64 Works with groups of 4 characters.  Each character represents 6 bits, so each group of 4 decodes into 3 bytes (8 bits per byte).  The only exception is the last 4 characters which will vary depending on the number of `=` signs.  Base64 strings will always be divisible by 4.

- 0 decodes to 3 bytes
- 1 = decodes to 2 bytes
- 2 == decodes to 1 byte

In your example `Hell` and `oWor` are both valid.  But `ld==` isn't.  To understand why see this lookup table:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

`ld==` should decode to only one byte because it has two `=` at the end.  But `ld` decodes to:  `100101 011101`.  A byte is only eight 8 bits.  So when you decode your string with `base64 -d`, only `100101 01` will be converted into a byte and the end `1101` will be ignored completely.

Any base 64 string ending in `==` must only use the first two bits of the last character.  That is the only valid endings with `==` are `Q==` `A==` `w==` `g==`

Answer (score 2):

The piping is not in order. You should encode first, before you decode.

```
$ echo "Hello World!==" | base64 | base64 -id
Hello World!==
```

You were decoding an invalid base64 encode format.

Comment: Is HelloWorld== not a valid base64 encoded string? Shouldn't I be able to convert it to binary and back to base64 without losing anything?

Comment: I thought the same until I read the whole question: My intention is to start with Base64 and end with Base64 (unfortunately this may have been added after your answer).

Comment: It was added later--after I realized (thanks to this answer) that it looked like a simple transposition error on my part.